# I know it's been discussed however bootstrap tooltip does not work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I've tried everything... Here is my code.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
</body
```

However, it gives me these errors.

1. jQuery.Deferred exception: $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip is not a function. (In '$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip()', '$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip' is undefined)
2. TypeError: $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip is not a function. (In '$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip()', '$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip' is undefined)

Please help

Comment: Using your code I'm not getting these errors. `$("[rel='tooltip']")` doesn't match anything in your code, but if I simply do `$("button")` instead it works perfectly fine. Please create a proper [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js scripts should be placed before the closing body tag (yours is btw missing '>', maybe a typo?) Anyhow, I got the tooltip to work with the following libraries and positioning (all cdns are from [Bootstrap 4: getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)):

Head:

```
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
```

Body:

```
 <body>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      data-placement="top"
      title="Tooltip on top"
    >
      Tooltip on top
    </button>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works once I put libraries scripts inside the body tag just as you advised